# phpMyAdmin hangs server by doing a COUNT(*) when going to "Browse"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, innodb

I have a very large table (~115 million rows). When I click it in phpMyAdmin everything blows up. By doing a `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` I can see that it's because phpMyAdmin has tried to execute the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `friend_map`.`connections`
```

Since this is an `innoDB` table this requires a table scan and the server errors out before returning.

It gives the error:

```
Error in Processing Request
Error code: 504
Error text: Gateway Timeout
```

I have to manually kill the mysql process or the entire database remains unresponsive.

Is there a way to tell phpMyAdmin not to execute this query?

Edit: I should probably also note that I'm in the middle of a server migration. This worked fine with phpMyAdmin 3.5.1 but now I've switched to new servers and this error is happening on phpMyAdmin 4.1.3.

Comment: `$cfg['MaxExactCount'] = 0;` Read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14027437/1129785

Comment: Thanks, that looks like exactly what I'm looking for! Unfortunately even after setting it to 0 it is still trying to do a count.

Comment: In fact, looking at [the documentation](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html?highlight=maxexactcount#cfg_MaxExactCount), it appears that 0 is the default value as well.

Comment: Thanks @Paul you pointed me in the right direction. I now see there is an open issue that this setting is getting ignored: http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/4027/?page=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an open issue with phpMyAdmin 4.x. More details are here: http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/4027/?page=0

I was able to fix this by adding `$force_exact = false;` to line 573 of libraries/Table.class.php.